Problem calling cgns library in fortran subroutines
I'm trying to extract x,y,z coordinates from a cgns 2-D mesh file.
I am using a Fortran 90 code and I use the cg_coord_read_f.
I have to call this function many times. So, I want to run the process using subroutine. But it isn't work.
The first version is following. It open the test.cgns file, and read CoordinateX, print them.
        program extractor_panel
        use cgns
        parameter (izmx=200,iptmx=100000)
        integer(4) :: index_file, index_zone, index_base, ier
        dimension x(iptmx,izmx)

        call cg_open_f('test.cgns',CG_MODE_READ,index_file,ier)

        index_file = 1
        index_zone = 1
        index_base = 1
        irmin=1
        irmax=100
        
        call cg_coord_read_f(index_file, index_zone, index_base, "CoordinateX", RealSingle, irmin, irmax, x, ier)
        print *, x(1,1), x(2,1), x(3,1), x(4,1), x(5,1)
        
        end program

The second version is following.
        program extractor_panel
        ! use cgns
        parameter (izmx=200,iptmx=100000)
        character*9 :: filename

        filename = 'test.cgns'
        
        call test(filename)
        
        end program

        subroutine test(filename)
        parameter (izmx=200,iptmx=100000)
        character*9 :: filename
        integer(4) :: index_file, index_zone, index_base, ier, irmin, irmax
        dimension x(iptmx,izmx)

        call cg_open_f(filename,CG_MODE_READ,index_file,ier)

        index_file=1
        index_zone=1
        index_base=1
        irmin=1
        irmax=10

        call cg_coord_read_f(index_file, index_zone, index_base, "CoordinateX", RealSingle, irmin, irmax, x, ier)
        print *, x(1,1), x(2,1), x(3,1), x(4,1), x(5,1)
        
        end subroutine

The second version simply moves the calling functions into a subroutine. However, the second version has the problem of returning all CoordinateXs to 0.0000.
Because the first version is working well, so there is no problem with cgns and hdf5 libraries.
How can I solve this problem?
It is compiled with 8bit real and integer. There is no problem with cgns and hdf5 libraries. (First version is working well.)

Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Follow the instructions shown in the short description o every tag shown when adding them. Be aware that a .f90 file exension does not mean Fortran 90 but the free source form for any modern version of Fortran.

Your code certainly is not combiled with "8bit real and integer". Probably some 8-byte, but there are multiple different ways. You should show the exact compiler flags you are using and report the exact compiler version.

Hint: Always, always use Implicit None I can't swear that is the error but it will help you find one o vious problem

To make Ian Bush's allusion concrete: the program version has use cgns and the subroutine version hasn't use cgns. That's a massive difference and can easily explain things.
